# Unable to centralise nav bar

Tags: html, css, nav

I am building a booking website for a cinema.

I have created a navbar, but am unable to centralize the options. I tried to use text-align: center; but it did not work.

I am using only HTML and CSS to build this site.

This is the first time posting on this platform and I am not sure if the information which I shared is sufficient.

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  max-width: 1042px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 23, 57);
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(230, 23, 57);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  width: 145px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Meta tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="Carnival Cinema">
  <meta name="keywords" content="cinema, indian movies, Carnival, Carnival Cinema">

  <!-- CSS Links -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">

  <title>Carnival Cinema</title>

</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <h1>Welcome to Carnival Cinema!</h1>

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Movies</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Now Showing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Corporations</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advertisement</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vouchers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <body>

  </body>

  <footer></footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
remove `float` from `nav ul`

```
    nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

Apart from this I would recommend to use rather display: flex instead of float. Is easier to handle and gives better possibilities for aligning, centering... But in this case `display: inline-block` is the easiest option.

And I also recommend to not give a fixed height to `nav` but rather do the spacing over the `margin` of `nav li a`. Like this it's always vertically centered as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` to the `nav`. I recommend to read more about Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/